# Why should the first root on firebase be named `users`?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `firebase` to handle my data for `react native` apps. I am new to both of them. I use:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/myEmployess/`).push({ name, phone, shift });
```

To push the data. My question is why the first root should be named `users`? for instance, i used `myUsers` and it did create anything on the firebase.

Comment: Any child can be named whatever you like - there is no requirement. If you are unable to write to myUsers, it's most likely because your [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) are preventing it. Check that first. Your currentUser.uid could be nil as well - there are a number of other things so do some research and update the question with what you found.

Comment: @Jay  you were right, that was because the RULES, please add it as an answer, thanks